# Passport Facebook authentication on cloud 9

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, passport-facebook

I am trying to use Passport Facebook authentication on cloude 9. The call back is always failing giving an error

`This site can’t provide a secure connection
webdevdk-******.c9users.io sent an invalid response.`

The call back module is

```
module.exports = {
'facebookAuth' : {
    'clientID': '***********',
    'clientSecret': '*******************',
    'callbackURL': 'https://webdevdk-******.c9users.io:80/auth/facebook/callback'
}};
```

My routes are

```
    app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email'] })
);



   app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
                                      failureRedirect: '/' }));
```

My facebook app setting are

```
  app domain :    webdevdk-*******.c9users.io

  site URL   :    webdevdk-*******.c9users.io:80/

  Valid OAuth redirect URIs : webdevdk******.c9users.io:80/auth/facebook/callback
```

Am I missing somthing ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this through a preview tab in the IDE itself, or are you opening the preview in a separate tab/window in your browser? Testing AJAX calls to https endpoints in the IDE do not work due to SSL issues (since the preview tab is an iframe). If you're currently attempting to test your application through the IDE, try testing in a separate tab instead.